# Object to 'hook' into jQuery function, possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hook, iteration

I am currently running into the following issue, which I'd like to solve more elegantly:

My script works as follows:

1. Takes an element
2. Puts the element into a container (defined as `var container = $('<div></div>'`) by using `.append()`
3. Keeps track of how far the container is 'filled'
4. If the container is full, `clone` a new container and continue there
5. Repeat this until every element is processed

Right now, this requires me to keep track of a 'fill' (and a 'max') variable to determine how far the container has been filled. So each time I do an `append()`, I have to increment these counters.

Now, what to me would be more elegant is making the `container` object smart, and enabling it to 'hook' into the `append()` event: whenever something is appended, the container object itself executes some code (incrementing its own counter, deciding if it is full, and if it is, returning a new, empty container).

I thought of solving it this way, by creating a function that returns a container:

```
var container = {
    template : $('<div class="container"></div>'),
    containers : [],
    get : function (i) {
        if (!this.containers[i]) {
            this.containers[i] = this.template.clone()
                .addClass('container-'+i)
                .data('max', 500); //this determines the maximum (px) the container can hold
        }
        return this.containers[i];
    }
};
```

This works, as I can now iterate over all the elements, and call `container.get(i).append(element)` for each one (while keeping count of height seperately and comparing that to `container().get(i).data().max`) and later in the script, when I need the output, I can return the `container.containers` object.

But I can't get it to work having the `container.get` function to 'watch' for an `append()` and act on it. I know this is not the way jQuery is meant to work, but I am sure there is another way of doing it, other than keeping local counters in the element iterator.

One other thing I tried is trying to set `.on($.append, function() { //do stuff });` on the container, but that was a pipe dream..

I hope I have explained everything clearly, and would love to know if someone has a solution to this.

**[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pBAEu/)** for a 'working' example (I highly doubt my programming skills)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
(function($)
{
    var oldappend = $.fn.append;
    var count = 0;

    $.fn.newAppend = function()
    {
        var ret = oldappend.apply(this, arguments);
        //your logic goes here 
        // count++;            

        return ret;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Or you need to store the count variable per container:

```
(function($)
    {
        var oldappend = $.fn.append;

        $.fn.newAppend = function()
        {
            var ret = oldappend.apply(this, arguments);
            //your logic goes here 
            if (!this.count){
                this.count = 0;
            }
            this.count++;

            return ret;
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Use it:

```
$('<div class="container"></div>').newAppend(yourElement);
```

Comment: That's clever, why didn't I think of prototyping a new append functioN :) This looks about right. Let me try to integrate it into the code

Comment: How can I reference the element that is being put in from within the newAppend function? ('yourElement') in your code EDIT: never mind, figured it out (by changing to '$.fn.newAppend = function (element)')

Comment: in this case, it's the arguments[0]

Comment: @c_kick: yes: function(element) and arguments[0] refer to the same thing.